# si necesito sacar solo los números enteros de un array ya hecha, lo hago con modulo para que me arroje solo aquellos que dan === 0

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

tengo un ejercicio que no logro completar su sintaxis, entiendo que para sacar de una lista solo los números enteros tengo efectuar una operación por ejemplo modulo, la cual solo es efectiva si el tipo de dato es un numero, si no llega a serlo lo descarta, basando esta lógica hice un función:

como verán lo que hice fue crear una variable donde guardare mi codigo nuevo, creo un ciclo for para  iterar en cada elemento y usando mi logica conclui que si diviendo en el mismo elemento da 0 es porque es un numero, porque si fuera un string no se efectuaria la operación, Bueno esta es mi pregunta, creo que hay un metodo simple pero bueno por lo que estudie esta es mi idea pero no se efectu así que agradezco su ayuda.

```
function soloNumeros(array) {
  // La funcion llamada 'soloNumeros' recibe como argumento un arreglo de enteros y strings llamado 'array'.
  // Debe devolver un arreglo con solo los enteros.
  // Ej: 
  // soloNumeros([1, 'hola', 2]) debe retornar [1, 2]

  // Tu código aca:
var soloenteros = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if (array[i] / array[i === 0) { soloenteros = array[i]}; 
 }
  return soloenteros;
}
```

Comment: vi que en un array me fato ] pero igual si lo coloque bien y aun así no lo saca.

Comment: Toma en cuenta por favor las observaciones que nos hizo a todos @MauricioContreras, no solo por la utilidad de ese conocimiento sino además por qué reducirá el código propuesto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo faltaria un par de detalles para entender mejor:

- Una forma comun de identificar que el elemento sea un numero cualquiera  (entero o decimal) es usando `if (typeof(variable) == "number") {}`, si especificamente espera solo enteros (sin decimales) entonces puedes usar `if (isInteger(variable)) {}` . Para solo decimales (no enteros) puedes usar `if (variable % 1 != 0) {}`
- para llenar un array sin necesidad de saber el indice donde agregar (simplemente agregar al final) se puede usar `soloenteros.push(array[i])`. Tambien puede servir usar `soloenteros[i] = array[i]` pero el indice quedara desfasado

```js
var input = [1 ,'hola', 2];

function soloNumeros(array){
  var soloenteros = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(array[i])=="number") { 
//       soloenteros[i] = array[i];
       soloenteros.push(array[i]);
    }; 
  }
 return soloenteros;
}  

console.log(soloNumeros(input));
```

Comment: Agregué informacion para tres casos distintos (numero general, entero o decimal)

Comment: La verdad nose que puedo decir, me solucionarón la interpretaciónd e una manera impresionante, les agradezco mucho su ayuda y wow super rapido todo.

Comment: No recomiendo usar `typeof` para determinar el tipo de variable. `typeof NaN` devuelve `"number"`. Y así encontrarás otros aspectos de `typeof` muy particulares del lenguaje. Saludos

Answer (score 5):

Partiendo de la solución ya propuesta podemos:

- Ahorrarnos el recorrido (al menos de forma visible) usando a filter
- Tampoco necesitamos un vector vacío que llenar pues filter nos retornará un vector con los elementos que cumplan la condición
- Las condiciones para el filtro las comparto enteramente con quién respondió, te invito a leer [sobre Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isInteger)

Propuesta

```
let numeros = [true, 1, 6.8];

let filtrados = numeros.filter(numero =>  Number.isInteger(numero));

 console.log(filtrados);
```

Observación de Mauricio Contreras

> El uso de typeof no es técnicamente necesario. Puedes usar solo isInteger() ya que todo valor analizado que no sea entero (numérico o no) retornará false

Comment: El uso de `typeof` no es técnicamente necesario. Puedes usar solo `isInteger()` ya que todo valor analizado que no sea entero (numérico o no) retornará `false`. Saludos

Comment: No la elimines, edítala. Y de paso puedes añadir el `polyfill` que aparece en la documentación de MDN, ya que `Number.isInteger` no funciona en IE. Y aunque parezca mentira aún hay navegadores IE funcionando por la web. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras editada agradezco siempre tu consejo y guía, aprendo mucho de ti, has logrado que esta publicación mejore y se maneje de mejor forma